# Sbt: How to define task for all projects?

Tags: scala, sbt

I would like to be able to define a task for all projects in my `sbt.build`:

```
lazy val project1 = project.in(`.` /  "project1)
   ...
lazy val project2 = 
   ...

lazy val upload = taskKey[Unit]("upload a config file from project to server)
upload := { 
   val file = baseDirectory.value / "config.json"
   ...
}
```

The problem is this definition works only when I call `sbt upload`, but I would like to be able to call it for each subproject: `sbt project1/upload` and `sbt project2/upload`.

Is there a way to do it, without using `inputKey`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [Organizing the build](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Organizing-Build.html#Defining+auto+plugins):

> For more advanced users, another way of organizing your build is to define one-off [auto plugins](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Plugins.html) in `project/*.scala`. By defining triggered plugins, auto plugins can be used as a convenient way to inject custom tasks and commands across all subprojects.

#### project/UploadPlugin.scala

```scala
package something

import sbt._
import Keys._

object UploadPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  override def requires = sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin
  override def trigger = allRequirements

  object autoImport {
    val upload = taskKey[Unit]("upload a config file from project to server")
  }
  import autoImport._

  override lazy val projectSettings = Seq(
    upload := {
      val n = name.value
      println(s"uploading $n..")
    }
  )
}
```

#### build.sbt

Here's how you can use it:

```
ThisBuild / organization := "com.example"
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.5"
ThisBuild / version      := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(project1, project2)
  .settings(
    name := "Hello"
  )

lazy val project1 = (project in file("project1"))

lazy val project2 = (project in file("project2"))
```

`build.sbt` does not have to mention anything about `UploadPlugin`, since it's a triggered plugin. From the shell you can call:

```
sbt:Hello> project1/upload
uploading project1..
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jul 20, 2018
sbt:Hello> project2/upload
uploading project2..
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jul 20, 2018
```

Comment: This is sooo hard to find useful information in SBT docs. Thank you Eugene!

Answer (score -3):

You can add the task as a setting of the project you want :

```
lazy val uploadTask = {
   lazy val upload = taskKey[Unit]("upload a config file from project to server)
upload := { 
   val file = baseDirectory.value / "config.json"
   ...
   }
}

project.in(`.` /  "project1).settings(uploadTask)
```

Comment: This does not address the OP's question of injecting the task to _all_ subprojects.

Comment: That's not how I understand the question, but as long as OP finds an answer, it doesn't really matter anyway